# Get json api data from another api flask

Tags: python, api, flask, sqlalchemy

i created this rest api with flask and sql alchemy and i want to not enter the json data manually but get it from another json and add it to my database :
https://www.habitat.fr/api/qDbBye4V7vtMu8qL97vvHTAnLQuEhC/product/911095/sku

my add product route in flask

```
#add product 
@app.route('/product', methods=['POST'])
def add_product():
    name = request.json['name']
    description = request.json['description']
    price = request.json['price']
    qty = request.json['qty']

    new_product = Product(name,description,price,qty)
    db.session.add(new_product)
    db.session.commit()

    return product_schema.jsonify(new_product)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need do is write a function using `requests` and `json` modules to fetch the json in the url like this:

```
import requests
import json
def get_data():
    r = requests.get('https://www.habitat.fr/api/qDbBye4V7vtMu8qL97vvHTAnLQuEhC/product/911095/sku')
    return json.loads(r.content) #convert content to dict
```

You may now call the function in your flask app:

```
@app.route('/product', methods=['POST'])
    def add_product():
    my_data = get_data()
    name = my_data['name']
    description = my_data['description']
    price = my_data['price']
    qty = my_data['qty']
```

Comment: That's because you dictionary keys `name` doesn't exist in the JSON data, you should go through the JSON file and be sure of what keys are available

Comment: i changed all the keys to fit with the JSON data but still not working